# Python string replacement with token values

Tags: string, python-3.x

I'm writing a Discord bot in Python 3 and wish to do URL conversion from http/https to steam.

For example, something like

```
https://store.steampowered.com/app/286160/
```

will become

```
steam://store/286160
```

Is there an easy way to do this that can easily be added to?

Comment: You can give [urllib.parse.urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) a try

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.

i should have mentioned this link
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol

though, i think i can work with the responses, ill mark what worked best for me with a comment on what i did differently when i get to that soon

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple `split`

```
>>> "steam://store/"+url.split("/")[-2]
```

---

```
>>> url = "https://store.steampowered.com/app/286160/"
>>> steam_url = "steam://store/"+url.split("/")[-2]
>>> print steam_url
steam://store/286160
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Andrew**, you can also try the below approach.

```
>>> inp = "https://store.steampowered.com/app/286160/"
>>>
>>> inp_url = "https://store.steampowered.com/app/286160/"
>>> arr = inp_url.split('://')
>>> arr
['https', 'store.steampowered.com/app/286160/']
>>>
>>> domain = arr[1].split('.')
>>> domain
['store', 'steampowered', 'com/app/286160/']
>>>
>>> sub_url = domain[-1].split('/')[-2]
>>> sub_url
'286160'
>>>
>>> out_url = 'stream://' + domain[0] + '/' + sub_url + '/'
>>> out_url
'stream://store/286160/'
>>>
```

Finally, you can design the below function to reuse the implemented code for number of urls.

#### Python code

```
def get_modified_url(inp_url, protocol='stream'):
    arr = inp_url.split('://')[1].split('.')
    sub_url1 = arr[0]
    sub_url2 = arr[-1].split('/')[-2]
    out_url = protocol + '://' + '/'.join([sub_url1, sub_url2])

    return out_url

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # INPUT 1 (Use default protocol as stream)
    url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/app/286160/'
    output = get_modified_url(url)
    print output

    # INPUT 2 (Override default protocol)
    url2 = 'https://store.steampowered.com/app/286560/'
    output2 = get_modified_url(url2, 'new_stream')
    print output2

    # INPUT 3 (Override default protocol)
    url3 = 'https://the_store2.steampowered.com/app/286161/'
    output3 = get_modified_url(url3, 'new_stream')
    print output3
```

#### Output

```
stream://store/286160
new_stream://store/286560
new_stream://the_store2/286161
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the URL by using `re` in Python like this.

```
import re

url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/app/286160/'

new_url = 'steam://store/' + re.split('/', url)[-2]

print(new_url) # output - steam://store/286160
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = "https://store.steampowered.com/app/286160/"
o = urlparse(url)

a = url.split(".")[0] 

b = url.split("/")[-2]

c = a.replace(o.scheme,"steam")

print(c + "/" + b)
```